# getting No provider error when I add service in provider in Component

Tags: angular6

I have a service, `HelperService` which is used by `NavComponentComponent`.

```
@Injectable()
export class HelperService {
...
}
```

nav-component.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav-component',
  templateUrl: './nav-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav-component.component.css'],
  providers:[UserManagementService,
    HelperService]
})
export class NavComponentComponent implements OnInit  {

  constructor(private userManagementService: UserManagementService, private fb:FormBuilder, private helper:HelperService) {

}
..
}
```

I am using `NavComponent` in `AppComponent`

```
<app-nav-component></app-nav-component>
```

But I am getting error

```
ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[NavComponentComponent -> HelperService]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[NavComponentComponent -> HelperService]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for HelperService!
    at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (core.js:1062)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1300)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1244)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:1141)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1300)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1244)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:1141)
```

But when I provided the services a module level, my program worked! Why just using `providers:HelperService` in `NavComponent` didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but probably the reason was that the `HelperService` was also used by a `AuthService` which was getting added using `UserManagementService`. I reckon that `Angular` tries to inject `UserManagementService` and finds that there is no way to add `HelperService`. To solve the issue, I inject `HelperService` at module level so that it becomes available to all components.

I wondered if reversing the order of services in `providers` at component level would work  but it didn't i.e. neither `providers:[UserManagementService, HelperService]` nor   `providers:[HelperService,UserManagementService]` worked